# Comodo SSL certificates in HAProxy on CentOS7

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, haproxy, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 server with HAProxy 1.6 as front and Apache 2.4 as back.

I am trying to load the SSL certificates in HAProxy, however it expects a `.pem` file.

I have got the following files from Comodo:

- cabundle.crt
- certificate.crt
- certificate.key
- certificate.p7b

And tried to merge the `certificate.crt` and `certificate.key`:

```
cat certificate.crt certificate.key > haproxy1.pem
```

This works sofar, however a get a regular `Chain Issues` error.
Also tried to merge `cabundle.crt`, `certificate.crt` and `certificate.key` into one `.pem` file. But this gives me an `SSL handshake failure` in the HAProxy log.

How to get this working correctly?

**File contents**

*cabundle.crt*

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

*certificate.crt*

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

*certificate.key*

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
hash
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

*haproxy.cfg*

```
frontend public
    bind            *:80
    bind            *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/private/
```

Comment: FYI: the data between `----BEGIN something` and `-----END something` in PEM-format files is base64-encoded, but is not a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this by doing the following:

My ISP gives me an decrypted private key if I provide the passphrase, but this gives me a different result then when I decrypt it myself using openssl.

So I downloaded the encrypted version and decrypted it myself using the passphrase:

```
openssl rsa -in certificate.key -out rsa.key
```

This gives me a file starting with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` instead of `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` from the ISP and a different base64 content.

Also, apparently the `cabundle.crt` includes a root certificate (this first block), which is not necessary, so I removed this one.

Next, I merged these files together:

```
cat certificate.crt cabundle.crt rsa.key > domain.com.pem
```

Also specified it directly in the `haproxy.cfg` file, to prevent loading the wrong file:

```
frontend public
    bind            *:80
    bind            *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/domain.com.pem
```

I'm still getting a *Chain Issues: Incorrect order* warning from SSLLabs, but it's working nevertheless, so it doesn't really bother me.

Comment: Thank you Man, it solve my issue, Yes the give Private key which is required to decrypt and have to use that in pem file